# jquery live and : problem

Tags: jquery, jdeveloper

```
$('#ptadsd1:r1:0:cbN89').live('click', function(event1) { 
    alert('clicked'); 
    return false; 
});
```

does not work becouse jdeveloper uses ":" when creating IDs.

my id is `"ptadsd1:r1:0:cbN89"` for example. Jdeveloper use ":" when creating ids but jquery has problem with it. How can i solve the problem with ":"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the `:` with a `\`. But to prevent JavaScript from treating the `\:` as a single character, you need to double escape it:

```
$('#ptadsd1\\:r1\\:0\\:cbN89');
```

---

**Relevant reference:**

> If you wish to use any of the
>   meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a
>   literal part of a name, you must
>   escape the character with two
>   backslashes: \\. For example, if you
>   have an an element with id="foo.bar",
>   you can use the selector
>   $("#foo\\.bar").

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/